# Makefile pattern rules with subdirectories

Tags: makefile

Assume I have some project directory with /src /out and /obj. I am trying to use pattern rules to compile all .c files from /src to /obj. If I dont use pattern rules like this:

```
CFlags := -Wall -Werror
obj := $(CURDIR)/obj
src := $(CURDIR)/src
out := $(CURDIR)/out

$(out)/byte: $(obj)/main.o $(obj)/test.o
    $(CC) $(CFlags) $^ -o $@

$(obj)/main.o: $(src)/main.c
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -c $< -o $@

$(obj)/test.o: $(src)/test.c $(src)/test.h
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm $(out)/byte $(obj)/*.o
```

everything works as expected. But if I replace the targets with the pattern rules like this:

```
CC := gcc
CFlags := -Wall -Werror
obj := $(CURDIR)/obj
src := $(CURDIR)/src
out := $(CURDIR)/out

$(out)/byte: $(obj)/main.o $(obj)/test.o
    $(CC) $(CFlags) $^ -o $@

$(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(src)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFlags) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm $(out)/byte $(obj)/*.o
```

I get an error:
`make: *** No rule to make target '/home/tobias/C/lib/obj/main.o', needed by '/home/tobias/C/lib/out/byte'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a file `src/main.h`?  If you don't then this pattern rule:

```
$(obj)/%.o: $(src)/%.c $(src)/%.h
```

can't be used to build `obj/main.o` because it can't match unless ALL the listed prerequisites exist.

For this reason it's highly unusual to include the header files in your pattern rule unless you have a requirement in your system *every single* `.c` file *must* have a related `.h` file.

Comment: No I don´t have a main.h file but lets assume I have some .c files that have a header file. How do I make pattern rules that respect whether or not a .c file has a corresponding .h file?

Comment: You don't.  You put the header file prerequisites somewhere else, outside of the pattern rule.  For example, `foo.o: foo.h bar.h baz.h` etc.  You can, if you are ambitious, enhance your makefile to automatically generate these prerequisites for you so you don't have to maintain them by hand.  See, for example: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/